# Program doesn't stop in "getline"

Tags: c++

I already tried to find the solution on the Internet, but I can't just find it in my situation.

In this function, when I called `getline(cin,line)`, the program doesn't stop to insert the value. If I change to, for example, `cin >> line` everything works perfectly.

```
void AddPeople(vector <People*> people_list)
{
    system("CLS");
    string line;
    string first_name, second_name, third_name;
    string delimiter = " ";
    size_t pos = 0;
    string token;
    int i=0;

    cout << "MENU::Add name" << endl;
    cout << "Name: ";
    getline(cin, line);

    while ((pos = line.find(delimiter)) != string::npos) 
    {
        token = line.substr(0, pos);
        line.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
        i++;
        if(i==1)
        {
            first_name=token;
        }
        else if (i=2)
        {
            second_name=token;
            third_name=line;
        }
    }

    people_list.push_back(new People(first_name, second_name, third_name));
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? Using g++ getline(cin, line) works fine (as it should). Also that comparison at else if is missing an '=' - pay attention to your compiler warnings :)

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012. And the compiler doesn't show me any warning @dabhaid

Comment: Visual studio is slightly stupid in that regard. A lot of fellow coders will recommend putting the constant first in the comparison. E.g. if( 2 == i ). That way if you miss an = sign, it will fail to compile.

Comment: Are you aware that this function has no effect whatsoever on the original vector? It's called `AddPeople`, and it does, but modifying a **copy** of the one given as argument. Is this the intended behavior? If not, pass the argument by reference.

Comment: I know about it, but my professor only let me use Visual Studio, and don't ask me why, i can't understand as well @steveg89

Comment: @steveg89: A lot, lot more will say "don't use that nasty idiom".

Comment: Sounds like you should use a free compiler like the LLVM or GCC independently from class to check your work.  Even if you only have Windows, you should be able to use NetBeans and/or Eclipse with either compiler on Windows and/or MinGW.  Also consider obtaining a large enough flash drive to boot with Ubuntu, using either LLVM or GCC or both.  The LLVM based C++Builder 64-bit Windows compiler has two warnings around the else clause with the missing `=`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Very true, especially since most compilers will warn you about it. If you turn VS's warning level to 4 it will warn you as well. Personally I learned variable == constant, so reading the other way is a bit awkward when I find it in someone else's code.

Answer (score 1):

getline() behaves interestingly when given and end of line character.

Program:

```
int x;
std::cin>>x;
std::string a;
std::getline(std::cin, a);
```

When given input `"42\na\n"`, this will read 42 into `x` and `""` into a because there are 0 characters between `'2'` and `'\n'`. This can be fixed by calling `std::getline` in a loop while there is nothing in `a`.

Comment: I didn't get it propertly i think, but i tried to put 

`while(line.empty()){
 cout << "Name: ";
 getline(cin, line);
 }`

And it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

The execution of the code inside the loop will depend on how many words you insert in line.
In example, if line has 3 words like "firstName midName lastName" the result will be correct as expected:

```
first_name = "firstName";
second_name = "midName";
third_name = "lastName";
```

but if line only includes 2 words "firstName lastName", then only first_name will be extracted and the loop will not enter the second iteration of the loop since the only delimiter was erased in the first iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I experimented same trouble and remembered a simple solution.

Just clean your buffer with

```
fflush(stdin);
```

after a getline or before getting a new one.

Sorry for being here 7 yeasr late :'(